# Magento1 reindexing: running indexer from command is queuing instead of reindexing

Tags: magento-1, reindex, indexing, catalog-url-rewrite

I am trying to run Magento indexer with:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```

But I am getting:

```
Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
```

Which first made no sense to me, but when I checked the admin backend, I found out that **Catalog URL Rewrites** is in state **WAIT(IN QUEUE)** and when I force processing the queue from the backend I get the 500 error.
[image]
This means that running the indexer from command line is just putting the indexing process in queue, and is not actually doing the real indexing!

My question: is there any way to configure the indexing behaviour to not but processes into the queue and run then directly instead?

Comment: do you have a `.lock` file in your var/lock directory?

Comment: @BareFeet no I don't have a ```.lock``` file but I have in the /var/locks one file: ```asyncreindex.lock```

Comment: Sorry my previous comment was regarding m2. What happens when you try to reindex from magento admin?

Comment: @BareFeet as I said, when I tried to reindex from Magento admin I got the 500 error. I managed to solve that with increasing the memory_limit, and the indexing is working now from the backend, but I still don't understand why this queuing behavior, and why I cannot directly index from the shell!

Comment: can you change the mode from "Update on Save" to "Manual Update" and try again?

Comment: I did that already and it did not help. I am starting to think that this ```WAIT(IN QUEUE)``` is not a Magento standard and is done by some module ?

Comment: To be fair, I have never seen this before. I always thought there were four different states;  `pending`, `working`,  `require_reindex and `processing`. Do you have your cron jobs properly set up?